# Is it possible to convert a DWG file to LaTeX?

Tags: pdf, conversion, technical-drawing

I think this was never asked, or at least from what I saw questions have been asked more than 15 years ago and has become obsolete (I found this [recent link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113999/can-i-add-a-blueprint-technical-drawing-to-my-document) but it did not work for me). I want to tell you that recently I started using the [AutoCAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoCAD) program (version 2016) in 2 dimensions, so for the moment the 3 dimensions will be left for later. For those who do not know what the program is about, it is a software for 2D drawing or 3D models, with different options for printing, conversion to other files, design, colors, etc., all in a reliable and friendly environment.

**My intention is for you to help me decide if it is possible to convert a .DWG file to .PDF using exclusively `TeX` or `LaTeX`, and if possible do it in the easiest way possible (for a beginner who does not understand converting files to the `LaTeX` environment).** But for this I have some "conditions", since I did not even use the `\includegraphics` command but I do everything by hand, so this is something new (and interesting) for me (and for you too!). These conditions are that I use the TeXnicCenter program with the output "LaTeX -> PS -> PDF" and that I do not use the programming structures that `LaTeX` provides (such as conditionals, loops, etc.). Yes, the question is simple enough but the answer seems difficult.

I attached a [.DWG file (via Google Drive)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Lr3zm6izxZruDUFXmMcJUxOsP_AByW-b) with the drawing of some lines that form the well-known A4 sheet (210.00mm x 297.00mm), and the basic LaTeX code that should be used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{vmargin}

\setpapersize{A4}
\setmargins{2.2cm}
{0.5cm}
{16.5cm}
{23.42cm}
{30pt}
{1cm}
{0pt}
{2cm}

\begin{document}
Example of how I would like it to look:

\newpage

\includegraphics{Example.dwg} % With the possibility of maintaining the original characteristics, such as the size of the drawing, the colors, the thickness of the lines, etc.
\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image: Example in LaTeX]

Will it be easy to implement it?

If it is a question that does not correspond to the essence of the forum please indicate it to me and I will eliminate it as soon as possible.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should be able to make an EPS from AutoCAD, and that should import into your LaTeX->PS->PDF workflow. But most people would probably just export a PDF from AutoCAD and go straight from LaTeX->PDF with no PS intermediate step.

Comment: In addition you could convert it to SVG and then include it into a Ti*k*Z picture (`\usetikzlibrary{svg.path}`). This would allow you to use the same fonts for the labels as in the ambient document.

Comment: DWG is a binary format with many versions. So converting it exclusively with TeX or LaTeX is close to impossible (i.e. it would just take too much time to write the necessary macros).

Comment: @MikeRenfro You know that while I was taking a shower I thought about what you say to me, because AutoCAD has that option. And I thought "Who will say it first?" hahaha, thank you, it seems to be the best option to convert it to EPS and then insert it into the document.

Comment: Hello @marmot! Good idea. I'll see how I try, and if I get it wrong you know who I'm going to turn to `;)`.

Comment: @Mike It's what I was afraid for... Thank you.

Comment: Note that there are some limitations, see section 69 of the pgfmanual.

Comment: @marmot I do not understand what you mean. Section 69 talks about the mathematical engine (`pgfmath` package) and that if mathematical expressions are not required the expression is prefixed by a `+`. If you thought I was going to use the algorithms that LaTeX is going to take me a long time to learn and use them correctly `:P`.

Comment: You must be reading a *really* old version ;-) Please update your installation. TeXLive 2018 is out just now.

Comment: @marmot Oh yes you are right (when not), I had not noticed the manual on the CTAN page. It seems that the biggest problems are those of the arc command and uniqueness in the dimension (only `pt`), right?

Comment: I dunno if these will be problematic, just want to warn you not to be overly optimistic. There is also the issue that the number cannot be arbitrarily large.

Comment: @marmot Ok, I'm going to keep it in mind.